# Chrome and ftp link asking for credentials. In FF and IE works fine

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink, ftp

i got link on my website to some ftpserver for guests.
ftp://chrome_test:chromium@ftp.2n.cz
I specify username and password in link so when they click on it they go to ftp view and it they can read any folder they want. It's works fine in mozilla and ie i can go to all folders after clicking on the link.

When i open this link with Chrome i can see folder, but when i click on any folder chrome asking me about credentials. Any ideas how i can make it work on Chrome ? In mozilla and ie i doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
This worked until a few weeks ago.
It seems Chrome has changed in this respect...